# NLog - logging without writing it in code

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog, trace

I want to trace  whole movement in the class, for example "on method entry/on return from method/parameters/object creating etc".

```
[trackThis]
Class MyServiceClass{

 GetFromRepo(); //should be logged
 Save(); //schould be logged
}
```

But I don't want to write all the time

```
Logger.Log("something")
```

Can I accomplish this with NLog ? What I should "google" for ? I have been looking already but without success.

Comment: Google Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP). A framework I know is PostSharp. There are probably others. Some free, some paid. Maybe Castle can of help as well (see https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy.md)

Comment: Another option is using Fody. https://github.com/Fody/Fody